# VB.net XML Parsing

Tags: vb.net, xml-parsing

I have been given an XML file that comes from an API and I'm unable to read the field names. I can get the values of each field using the code below but I cannot figure out how to get the field names as well.

As you can see some of the fields do not have a value which will appear sometimes and not other so I need to know which values as under which field names.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sfd:payload mlns:sfd="http://www.wrt.com/types"model="http://ost.bro.com/api/r1">
  <sfd:field name="ptp.systemid">
    <sfd:value>Waiting for life</sfd:value>
  </sfd:field>
  <sfd:field name="ptp..itmid">
    <sfd:value>101602175821</sfd:value>
  </sfd:field>
  <sfd:field name="ptp.itmsi">
    <sfd:value>KTHDBATCHINGSPEED1802-A0ZSTKE2</sfd:value>
  </sfd:field>
  <sfd:field name="ptp.info">
    <sfd:value>PNC Code 10055017 K4354353534534534345</sfd:value>
  </sfd:field>
  <sfd:field name="ptp.start"/>
    <sfd:field name="ptp.end"/>
  </sfd:payload>

Dim xmllines As String = str.ReadToEnd
str.Close()

Dim output As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(xmllines))
    Do While (reader.Read())
        Select Case reader.NodeType
            Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.Value)
        End Select
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: Use `XElement`; it's _vastly_ easier to use.  Note that you will also need `XNamespace`.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, name is an attribute. You can use the GetAttribute method. For example:

```
    Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(xmllines))
        Do While (reader.Read())
            Select Case reader.NodeType
                Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                    Dim fieldName As String = reader.GetAttribute("name")
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(fieldName & " = " & reader.Value)
            End Select
        Loop
    End Using
```

Of course, declaring the string variable isn't necessary. You can use `reader.GetAttribute("name")` anywhere you need it.